# Checkboxes are responding slow in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am using twitter bootstrap along with jquery for achieving RWD. The checkboxes are responding fine in chrome/firefox.But in IE8 it is taking couple of seconds for checkbox responding i.e., on clicking checkbox it is taking some seconds to get it checking

Comment: Is only in IE 8 or maybe in all IEs? I had the same issue and it was caused by low JS performance in IE < 9.

Comment: It is occuring in all IEs.

Comment: this is not normal in IE8. Try removing all non-TBS scripts

Comment: Same problem exists even for IE 10. Check Bootstrap site in that browser.

Comment: The bootstrap checkboxes are responding fine in IE browsers.I tested with link http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/signin.html. Will the checkbox inside span will slower the responding time.My checkbox is like this <span class="pull-left"><input type="checkbox" /></span>

Comment: I am using jquery jquery-1.8.1.min.js.If I replace with jquery-1.8.3.min.js file as per suggestion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473765/bootsrap-js-slows-down-web-page-in-ie/13477836#13477836 .It is rendering fine.Is anyone knows reason for this.

Answer (score 2):

This is occuring because of usage of jquery-1.8.1 version.If I use jquery-1.8.3 version, the rendering of checkboxes are fine and also in fast manner.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this as well, and I determined the cause.

First of all, you need a large page with with a lot of DOM elements on it. In my example, I have a table with 10 columns and 100 rows, and each cell contains 1 or 2 elements as well.

The slowness if you profile it shows it is within jQuery itself. What is happening is there are a lot of .live() and .delegate() (err, the ".on" equivalents of them) calls in bootstrap, and jQuery has to handle events and run selector filters to determine if any of the handlers need to be called. One click of a checkbox for me was causing this to occur 17 times, and it's just dog slow in IE8 (ACTUAL IE8, not IE8 compat mode in IE9, mind you, there is a huge difference).

There's really no workaround or fix, it's just the nature of bootstrap to have these handlers, and IE8's nature to filter slowly.

You might be able to improve things by optimizing the size of the page, and by including only the aspects of bootstrap that you really need.